# How to customize title page in beamer so that it looks like

Tags: beamer, titles

How can I modify title page so that it looks like it is in [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q-B_ONJIEcE) video. Please seek to 16 seconds and watch title page. I do not have permission to post images. I liked this theme and I want to make a beamer theme that looks similar. I tried with beamercolorbox but I failed to position the box to the bottom.

[image]

---

Edit:
Here is my minimum working example

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{customized}[1][]
{
\usebeamerfont{subtitle}
\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}

{\flushright
\setbeamercolor{author}{bg=white,fg=Red}
\usebeamerfont{author} \insertauthor\par
\usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute\par }

\vspace{0.2in}

\setbeamercolor{postit}{fg=white,bg=YellowOrange}

\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=1em,wd=1.062\textwidth,ht=3cm,dp=3cm,right]{postit}
\usebeamerfont{title} {\huge \inserttitle}\par
\usebeamerfont{subtitle} {\insertsubtitle}
\end{beamercolorbox}
}
\usecolortheme[named=YellowOrange]{structure}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
\institute{Harvard College Professor and\\ Johnstone Family Professor in Psychology, Harvard University}

\title{SAY WHAT?}
\subtitle{Linguistics as a Window to\\ Understanding the Brain}
\author{Steven Pinker}

\begin{document}
{
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here's one possibility; I redefined the title page template and used TikZ's `\node`s to place the elements; `pdfrender` was used for the author and the title:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pdfrender}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\Huge}
\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\normalsize\itshape}
\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\fontsize{30}{36}\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{size=\Large\normalfont\slshape}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[orange]
  ([yshift=15pt]current page.west) rectangle (current page.south east);
\node[anchor=east] 
  at ([yshift=-50pt]current page.north east) (author)
  {\parbox[t]{.6\paperwidth}{\raggedleft%
    \usebeamerfont{author}\textcolor{orange}{%
    \textpdfrender{
    TextRenderingMode=FillStroke,
    FillColor=orange,
    LineWidth=.1ex,
    }{\insertauthor}}}};
\node[anchor=north east] 
  at ([yshift=-70pt]current page.north east) (institute)
  {\parbox[t]{.78\paperwidth}{\raggedleft%
    \usebeamerfont{institute}\textcolor{gray}{\insertinstitute}}};
\node[anchor=south west] 
  at ([yshift=20pt]current page.west) (logo)
  {\parbox[t]{.19\paperwidth}{\raggedleft%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic}};
\node[anchor=east]
  at ([yshift=-10pt,xshift=-20pt]current page.east) (title)
  {\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\raggedleft%
 \usebeamerfont{author}\textcolor{white}{%
    \textpdfrender{
    TextRenderingMode=FillStroke,
    FillColor=white,
    LineWidth=.1ex,
    }{\inserttitle}}}};
\node[anchor=east]
  at ([yshift=-60pt,xshift=-20pt]current page.east) (subtitle)
  {\parbox[t]{.6\paperwidth}{\raggedleft\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\textcolor{black}{\insertsubtitle}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\author{John Doe}
\institute{Harvard College Professor and\\ Johnstone Family Professor in Psychology, Harvard University}
\title{Say What?}
\subtitle{Linguistics as a Window for Understanding the Brain}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{ctanlion}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

CTAN lion drawing by Duane Bibby.

Feel free to adjust the lengths according to your needs.

Comment: Output is very close to what is required. I face a little problem when I compile this code. It says I can't find file `pgflibrarytikzpositioning.code.tex'. I searched for `pgflibrarytikzpositioning.code.tex` but couldn't find it.

Comment: @Aryaveer the positioning library is not needed to run my code; I've deleted it in my updated answer. However, the error you got suggest that you are using an outdated version of PGF. You should consider updating it or, even better, updating your LaTeX system.