# How customize title page in beamer?

Tags: beamer, titles, presentations

I'd like to create a title page for a presentation with `beamer` like this.

I saw something about modifying the inner theme but I don't understand how to place the logo of the university and the horizontal line to separate the upper from the lower part.

[image]

**Edit:**
This is a MWE of my title page. Instead the the orange I'd like to insert an image.
I don't want the header and the footer in the title page, but I don't know how to eliminate them.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\title[]{Title}
\date{28 luglio 2016}
\author[]{Author\\{\small Supervisor}}
\institute[]{Institute}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pdfrender}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\Large}
\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\fontsize{10}{10}\itshape}
\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\fontsize{30}{36}\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{size=\Large\normalfont\slshape}
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[orange]
  ([yshift=15pt]current page.west) rectangle (current page.south east);
\node[anchor=east] 
  at ([yshift=-50pt]current page.north east) (author)
  {\parbox[t]{.6\paperwidth}{\raggedleft%
    \usebeamerfont{author}\textcolor{orange}{%
    \textpdfrender{
    TextRenderingMode=FillStroke,
%    FillColor=orange,
%    LineWidth=.1ex,
    }{\insertauthor}}}};
\node[anchor=north east] 
  at ([yshift=-70pt]current page.north east) (institute)
  {\parbox[t]{.78\paperwidth}{\raggedleft%
    \usebeamerfont{institute}\textcolor{gray}{\insertinstitute}}};
\node[anchor=south west] 
  at ([yshift=20pt]current page.west) (logo)
  {\parbox[t]{.19\paperwidth}{\raggedleft%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic}};
\node[anchor=east]
  at ([yshift=-15pt,xshift=-20pt]current page.east) (title)
  {\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\raggedleft%
 \usebeamerfont{author}\textcolor{white}{%
    \textpdfrender{
    TextRenderingMode=FillStroke,
    FillColor=white,
    LineWidth=.1ex,
    }{\inserttitle}}}};
\node[anchor=east]
  at ([yshift=-60pt,xshift=-20pt]current page.east) (subtitle)
  {\parbox[t]{.6\paperwidth}{\raggedleft\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\textcolor{black}{\insertsubtitle}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{Sigillo.pdf}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: could you provide a MWE and show what you got so far?

Comment: I've no MWE cause my title page is default yet.

Comment: See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110925/how-to-customize-title-page-in-beamer-so-that-it-looks-like as something to start with.

Comment: Offtopic: but you should not use formatting commands inside fields such as `\author[]{Author\\{\small Supervisor}}`- this can cause all kinds of trouble. Better add such formatting commands to your definition  of the title page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pdfrender}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\title[]{Title}
\date{28 luglio 2016}
\author[]{Author{\small Supervisor}}
\institute[]{Institute}

\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\Large}
\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\fontsize{10}{10}\itshape}
\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\fontsize{30}{36}\bfseries}
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{size=\Large\normalfont\slshape}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor=south] at ([yshift=-0.15cm]current page.south) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=5cm]{example-grid-100x100bp}};
    \node[anchor=east] 
    at ([yshift=-50pt]current page.north east) (author)
    {\parbox[t]{.6\paperwidth}{\raggedleft%
            \usebeamerfont{author}\textcolor{orange}{%
                \textpdfrender{
                    TextRenderingMode=FillStroke,
                    %    FillColor=orange,
                    %    LineWidth=.1ex,
                }{\insertauthor}}}};
    \node[anchor=north east] 
    at ([yshift=-70pt]current page.north east) (institute)
    {\parbox[t]{.78\paperwidth}{\raggedleft%
            \usebeamerfont{institute}\textcolor{gray}{\insertinstitute}}};
    \node[anchor=south west] 
    at ([yshift=20pt]current page.west) (logo)
    {\parbox[t]{.19\paperwidth}{\raggedleft%
            \usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic}};
    \node[anchor=east]
    at ([yshift=-15pt,xshift=-20pt]current page.east) (title)
    {\parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\raggedleft%
            \usebeamerfont{author}\textcolor{white}{%
                \textpdfrender{
                    TextRenderingMode=FillStroke,
                    FillColor=white,
                    LineWidth=.1ex,
                }{\inserttitle}}}};
    \node[anchor=east]
    at ([yshift=-60pt,xshift=-20pt]current page.east) (subtitle)
    {\parbox[t]{.6\paperwidth}{\raggedleft\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\textcolor{black}{\insertsubtitle}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \maketitle
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]