# "Missing pdfTeX in PDF mode"

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

By running the given [code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110925/how-to-customize-title-page-in-beamer-so-that-it-looks-like/619580?noredirect=1#comment1547030_619580), I am getting the following error: "Missing pdfTeX in PDF mode" and I can not get the final pdf. Does anybody know how to solve it??

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: that is not a tex error, is it an error from your editor saying that it can not find pdftex?

Comment: Include a [example] in the question itself. A link to another question is not sufficient.

Comment: @user202729 the error is unlikely to be related to tex code.